# Axios Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios

I ve got a problem with axios in my react-native app.
The error message is provided here [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZYcL.png)    [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7a9E.png)
Actions.start()  never runs.

Edit 1: 
Heres the full code. 
Edit 2:
Picture of the error message[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1J0z.png)
As to the results the const res= await... should be the problem.
Have to add more details, otherwise I cant update this question ;)

```
export const apiPostLogin = (
 accountData
) => async dispatch => {
dispatch(setFetching(true));
try {
  var instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.xxxx.de/',
    timeout: 1000
 });

const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/login', accountData);
Actions.Start();

dispatch(setAuthToken(res.data.token));


  await dispatch(apiGetAccount(res.data.token));
  console.log(res);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response);
  dispatch(setFetching(false));
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
  dispatch(
    setApiResponse({
      apiResponse: true,
      didShowResponse: false,
      apiResponseError: true,
      apiResponseCode: 401,
      apiResponseMessage: 'E-Mail und Passwort stimmen nicht überein'
    })
  );
} else if (error.response.status === 417) {
  dispatch(
    setApiResponse({
      apiResponse: true,
      didShowResponse: false,
      apiResponseError: true,
      apiResponseCode: 417,
      apiResponseMessage: 'Du hast Deine E-Mail noch nicht bestätigt'
    })
  );
} else {
  dispatch(
    setApiResponse({
      apiResponse: true,
      didShowResponse: false,
      apiResponseError: true,
      apiResponseCode: 499,
      apiResponseMessage:
        'Du kannst Dich im Moment nicht bei uns anmelden. Wir befinden   uns im Wartungsmodus'
    })
   );
   }
  }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `post` call in a try catch (catch is essential for handling rejected promises) block. Your network request is getting failed. You need to catch the error / handle the promise rejection

```
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/login', accountData);
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(res.status);
        console.log(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Failure!');
        console.error(e.response.status);
        throw new Error(e);
    }
    Actions.Start();
```

OR 
try using `axios()` instead of `axios.create()`

```
return axios.({
    method: 'post',
    baseURL: userEndpoint,
    headers: {
        common: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        }
    }
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: Hey , thank you for your answer! But it still doesnt work. The whole block is also wrapped in a Try{} catch statement. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: yeah wait one second

Comment: Does `console.log(error.response);` gets executed in catch block?

Comment: Have you tried using it with `.then` instead of  `await`?

Comment: Hey, the console doesnt print the error response. When I tried with .then another error occured. Maybe I did it wrong, so I will try this again

Comment: delete every thing from the function just keep axios call and see what happens with `await` and with `.then`

Comment: It only pints TypeError: Network request faild in the console

Comment: So does it give you `Unhandled Promise Rejection` warning now?

Comment: hey I will try later. have to go afk. I will write my results later ;) Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it"!!!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if that worked for you. ;) Thanks

Comment: Hey, I printed out the error message. A screenshot is provided in my new edit. .then didnt work out

Comment: I also tried using fetch by react native. I got the same errors. Could It be any problem with my emulated android device?

Comment: thanks for that comment, it opened my mind, you probably faced the same problem that i am facing, that is, using `localhost` as api url, but i cant do that since a emulated device isnt on same host as the server, so i need to use `192.168.0.1` or something like that :)

Comment: I don't think there is supposed to be a period after `axios` in the second example is there?